# How to add a additional hover effect to scroll-bar

Tags: html, css

In my css I have changed the style of sroll bar and it looks like

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.7em;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(154,165,159,0.5);
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #D0CACD;
  outline: 1px solid LightGrey;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 50px grey;
}
```

It works. And if I add hover:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #b8c0bc; 
}
```

Then also it works when I add the webkit animation to it then why does it not works. After adding webkit animation then it totally looks like:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #b8c0bc;
  -webkit-animation: scrollbig 1s; 
  animation: scrollbig 2s; 
}
```

The animation does not play. Why ? I am using google chrome. And you can also see the `@keyframe` animation code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scrollbig {
  from {width: 0.6em;}
  to {width: 0.9em;}
}
```

Please tell how to make the animation works.
A Special Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I could imagine is that it's just not possible to animate a scrollbar. I've never seen a website with an animated scrollbar and would not see a reason why this should be done. But maybe someone else knows more about that.

Comment: Wait a second, -webkit-scrollbar-thumb does not select the scrollbar itself. You should try out -webkit-scrollbar as the element to use the animation on. See reference [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/)

Comment: @Lunaetic I have tried that but it dosent works.

Comment: Well then I believe that it just isn't possible to animate your scrollbar /:

Comment: There is already an answer in another same question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69820772/9854149

Answer (score 6):

As I can see it, there is a couple of reason to why this doesn't work.

You can't set the width of `body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`. It will always be the same as `body::-webkit-scrollbar`.

You can't change the width of `body::-webkit-scrollbar` on `:hover`. With or without an animation.

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.7em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    width: 0.9em; // Will be ignored
}
```

The `from` value of the `keyframes` rule will be set. But any animation on a scrollbar pseudo-element simply will not play.

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: yellow; // Scroll thumb is yellow
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    -webkit-animation: scrollbig 1s;
}

// 0% = from, 100% = to
@-webkit-keyframes scrollbig {
    0% {background: red;} // Scroll thumb is red
    1% {background: green;} // Will be ignored
    100% {background: blue;} // Will be ignored
}
```

Transitions are also ignored.

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: yellow; // Scroll thumb is yellow
    transition: background 2s; // Will be ignored
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: red; // Scroll thumb is red
}
```

Comment: You can change the width of a scrollbar on hover. See my answer

Answer (score -2):

This will change the width, unfortunately transitions still are not supported. (This is in sass)

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;

    &:hover {
      width: 4px;
    }
  }
```