# Custom scrollbar but keep disappearing effect

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to just change the colour of a scrollbar in CSS, but keep the native 'disappear when not scrolling' effect. Basically I just want to turn the native scrollbar blue instead of its default black/dark-grey, but whenever I apply code like this

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue; 
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

The scrollbar looks how I want it too, but its persistent, instead of disappearing when i'm not scrolling. Is there any way I can keep that effect on a custom scrollbar?

**EDIT - As requested my current browser is google chrome 73.0.3683.103**

Comment: Try not setting the width.

Comment: If I don't set the width, the custom scrollbar doesn't show at all

Comment: The scrollbar doesn't disappear with Chrome on Windows, so perhaps you could [edit] your question to mention the OS/Browser you're testing on...

Comment: Here is a fiddle it shows your CSS working? Just drag the results box. https://jsfiddle.net/kingafrojoe/Le253gdw/1/

Comment: If your planning to use this productively I wouldn't recommand using the type of styling. It's still not supported by Edge and only partly supported by other browsers: (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar). This issue that is not showing up might be an issue on the overflow on the parent element.

Comment: @Joe Its not working, it show the blue bar which I currently have anyway, but its not disappearing when I'm not scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

The most you can do using only css and webkit is to use the :hover/:active selectors to display or hide the scrollbar. The thing is, this will work on hover/selection and not on a finger swipe or a mouse wheel. Also this webkit property will not work on firefox or edge.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Info on [webkit scrollbar](https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230289/use-transition-on-webkit-scrollbar) has a nice example of a smooth transition on hover

Answer (score 0):

A late answer hopefully it still helps.

I don't think you can do this with pure CSS, (but i could be wrong)

You can use some jQuery to help you. I have a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kingafrojoe/Le253gdw/29/

In your CSS `.has-scroll` to the scrollbar selectors as below

```
/* Add a css class to your scroll selectors */
.has-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}
.has-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
.has-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#tall {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #00ffff;
    display: block;
}
```

In your HTML you will need a wrapper div wrapping the whole body of your document.
The body class also gets the class `has-scroll` jQuery will control this class.

```
<body class="has-scroll">
    <div id="site">

        <div id="tall"> I am tall content</div>

        <!-- ALL other page HTML -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then some jQuery to detect the height of the content and the window.
If the content is taller than the window then there needs to be a scrollbar, else the scrollbar can do default behavior

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(window).load(function(){

    var _body = $('body');
    var _site = $('#site');

    $(window).resize(function(){
        show_scroll();// call the function on the window resize
    });

    show_scroll();// call the function

    function show_scroll(){
        // if the content wrapper is taller than the window add the has-scroll class,
        // else remove the has scroll class to return default scroll behavior.
        if(_site.outerHeight()>$(window).outerHeight()){
            _body.addClass('has-scroll');
        }else{
            _body.removeClass('has-scroll');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```