# div element transition scrollbar bar color on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a scrollbar color change on `div` hover. I'm not sure what I'm missing or if its possible. Here's what I have. It's a simple HTML page that should updated scrollbar color on `body` hover

```css
/* width */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Handle */

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 5s ease-in-out;
}


/* Handle on hover */

body:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h2>Custom Scrollbar Example</h2>

  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The -webkit-scrollbar is not supported in Firefox or in Edge, prior version 79.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>

</body>
```

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet, removed the unnecessary HTML markup and moved the CSS to the CSS box. That said, what browser are you using? This works for me in Chrome, but not FireFox (as expected, per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar))

Comment: Im using both chrome and Edge. I'm expecting a smooth color transition when it changes from red to green.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css - apply transition in scrollbar-thumb pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257987/css-apply-transition-in-scrollbar-thumb-pseudo-element)

Comment: @AnthonyR ah, your question only indicated that you weren't seeing any color change. You didn't specify a transition. The duplicate answers your question.