# Can't add transition to scrollbar color on hover

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have made a custom scrollbar for my site which uses linear gradient color which changes on hover. However I am unable to change the color smoothly with a transition can anyone help me with this.
this is my CSS for the scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: #1b1b1b;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: linear-gradient(#757575,#2e2e2e);
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: background 0.5
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background: linear-gradient(#2e2e2e,#1b1b1b);
}
```

The `transition: background 0.5s;`dosent seem to work and I cannot use `color` instead of `background` to add color to the scrollbar thumb. Please tell me how I can add transition to the color of the scrollbar.

Comment: Gradient backgrounds don't support animation, you can check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212/use-css3-transitions-with-gradient-backgrounds, they are some workarounds but I quickly tried them and it doesn't work for scrollbar styling

Comment: And you can check this post too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230289/use-transition-on-webkit-scrollbar